# Get two values from command output in a bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, command, variable, output

I have a bashscript, which executes a command and calculates a pair of values, which output can look like this.

`a,b (10.0000000000, 10.0000000000) -> volt (2088133.7088034691, -222653.3238934391)`

And in case of invalid parameters or errors the program can show different error-messages.

Is there a safe way to parse the two volt-values and store them in two variables in a bash script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how reliable the output is and what happens when you get the "different error messages", ie., how that would have to be handled.

A basic approach, with what you have above, you could use `awk`:

```
awk -F"[)(, ]" '{printf "var1=%s\nvar2=%s\n", $11,$13}'      
var1=2088133.7088034691
var2=-222653.3238934391
```

A "safe way" would depend on *what* those error messages do to the output...

A more robust approach would be to use `awk`'s built-in `NF` variable to calculate the relevant fields:

```
awk -F"[)(, ]" '{printf "var1=%s\nvar2=%s\n", $(NF-3),$(NF-1)}'
```

Comment: Thanks! That works great. The error messages are, if the parameters are invalid, either the help of the program or just text of the sort ("For the given a,b the voltage can't be calculated") or if some other data is missing "Failed to read file".

Comment: @user3199134 Well, you could test for the error string(s) and if they don't appear, parse the output for your variables. That would make it *slightly* "safer"...

Comment: @jasonwryan Also it's better to use `$(NF-3),$(NF-1)` instead of `$11,$13` because if the length of line is not fix then when you use `$11,$13` may be it will be point to wrong index ;)

Comment: Thanks! I edited it. And the simple safety is, if the error messages are put out by the program, awk fails (runtime error because negative field index) and var1 and var2 are empty, if they are, I know an error happened.

It's not the safest and not the best solution, but it's still better than completely ignoring it.

Comment: @KasiyA That's an excellent suggestion: adding it. Thank you.

Comment: How about testing the return code of the program before attempting to parse its output? I guess we'd first need to test that the program does, in fact, set an appropriate return code. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring: Checked it, program always returns zero.